# An MFC application which is connecting oracle db through occi. but it is giving error 0xC000007b on running in 64 bit machine?

Tags: c++, oracle, mfc, 32bit-64bit, occi

I have compiled this application in VS 2010 in `32 bit Win7` and it is working fine on `32 bit machine` but giving error "the application is Unable to start correctly 0xc000007b" on 64 bit machine.

After Google it I have checked with `Dependency Walker` it is giving the error in `ORAOCCI11.dll`. but don't get any solution to resolve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried an static build ?

Comment: what do you mean by static build?

Comment: The error code is STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT.  Are you building a 64 bit app with a 32 bit oracle lib?

Comment: yes i am building the code on 32 bit machine with 32 bit occi lib

Comment: Is it possible that even though you are linking to the 32-bit version of the Oracle library that it is still trying to load the 64-bit version of the dll on 64-bit Windows. Especially if the Oracle dll names do not distinguish between 32/64-bitness.

Comment: i have tried with both by putting both dlls i.e. 32 bit and 64 bit on which system i am trying to install the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer of this question by my own so i am answering it. I should use all the 32 bit libraries even on 64 bit system if my all other code is complied in 32 bit so ODAC client should be of also 32 bit.